# Is there a built-in function into Android Studio to calculate the median of the values of an array?

Tags: median

I have an image, I would like to apply median filtter on it to enhanessment this image and eiminate image noise.

- I converted the image into  three of 2D arrays , one for each band (Red, Grean,Blue).
- I used the sort method and then got the (min) and max value.

Now I want to know: Is there a built-in function in java android studio to apply median on this arrays?

If there is no built-in function, Please help me with fill cod for median with the masks must applied on the images.

Thank you very much.